# GitHub: Get all changes of one particular file that are currently in pull requests

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I am working on a big repository that has many contributors and currently it has many open pull requests. I want to make changes to one file and I want to get all changes of that particular file that are in pull requests right now. Is there any way to do such a thing?

Comment: Certainly you can do this. But why? Are you anticipating merge conflicts? That's no way to collaborate.

Comment: Git doesn't know about PRs, this is a github thing. You will need to manually diff between your change and each PR's branch.

Comment: @evolutionbox : Github keeps refs that point to the current commit of each pull request, so there can be a good deal of scripting over that. What isn't clear in the OP's question is what he intends to do with those changes.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fetch upstream first to avoid conflicts and then once you made your changes, you can see all your changed files using command

```
git status
```

Answer (score -1):

[PR Merge Queues](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/configuring-pull-request-merges/managing-a-merge-queue) has been introduced recently and it will help with your situation.

Without a merge queue, changes in your PR will only be compared to the base branch. While with merge queues, your PR sees the base branch plus changes in all PRs ahead of you in the queue.